# How to get Gmail unread count

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am using the following code to get the Unread emails count in Gmail. However, it is returning the error:

```
can't connect: Too many login failures
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

(IMAP and POP are enabled in the Gmail account I am testing.)

---

***NOTE:** It looks like it is working (at least for most of the requests). However, it is taking way too long - maybe 2 - 3 minutes to come back with a number. Is there a way to speed it up?*

---

Thanks!

```
<?php

$mbox = imap_open ("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox", 
"username", "password", OP_READONLY) 
or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error()); 
$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($mbox); 
if ($check) { 
print $check->Unread; //. "/" . $check->Nmsgs; 
} else { 
print "Failed"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: instead of `imap_last_error()`, write : `print_r(imap_errors())`

Comment: @Igoris: (I don't think it is related to adding the print_r) but now it just gets stuck loading

Comment: It looks like it is working (taking way too long - maybe 2 - 3 minutes to come back with a number). Is there a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the [Gmail Inbox Feed](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/inbox_feed.html) to get the unread count.
Just send an authenticated GET request to https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom and check the value of the `fullcount` element.

Comment: How do you do that? in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting all of the errors that may have been encountered:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox", "username", "password", OP_READONLY) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . print_r(imap_errors()));
```

Comment: (I don't think it is related to adding the print_r) but now it just gets stuck loading

Comment: Try accessing your account manually and see if it allows you to login.  It may ask you for a captcha due to the failed attempts.

Comment: It looks like it is working (taking way too long - maybe 2 - 3 minutes to come back with a number). Is there a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and it is very simple.

Login with your account which is you use for imap connection and at the top of page google alter you about the multi location access your account so Goolge privent that so complete that process and enable to use your accout

and your problem will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make a authenticated GET request to gmail api.
url :: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/UNREAD

It will return a json with count of unread messages n threads.
countUnread = response["messagesTotal"].
For more details, refer to oauth 2 playground. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=4/-49VJwh28-eJG7xiK3UoFBchIQrCYRllnOt1TY-w0h4#