# How to get the number of unread gmail mails 

Tags: php, email, gmail

Can someone help me with a code to get the numbers of unread gmail emails to php?

Comment: i havent trie, because i don't know how to start

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003150/how-to-get-gmail-unread-count

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please always Google before asking. Googling `How to get the number of unread gmail mails php` turns up good results. Thanks!

Comment: Thx @all
<code><?php
$mbox = imap_open ("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox", "username", "password", OP_READONLY)
or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . print_r(imap_errors()));

$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($mbox);
if ($check) {
print $check->Unread; //. "/" . $check->Nmsgs;
} else {
print "Failed";
}

?>
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to gmail via IMAP protocol using functions from the IMAP module http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}INBOX", "username", "password")
     or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);

// Fetch an overview for all messages in INBOX
$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
$seen = 0;
$unseen = 0;
foreach ($result as $overview) {
    if($overview->seen){
      $counter++;
    } else {
      $unseen++;
    }
}
imap_close($mbox);

echo "Seen $seen, unseen $unseen"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some this API to get your inbox feed :  http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/inbox_feed.html

But there is plenty of libraries to access these feed in PHp I guess.